# Typescript generics infer instance type from class type

Tags: typescript, class, generics, instance

I have a generic wrapper function, which takes a class, and then needs to infer the instance type for the return type – but I'm having trouble getting this to work... For some extra context, this is for database querying using [Objection](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/).

Classes:

Note that the `Model` class comes from the Objection library.

```
class Model {
  static query<T>(this: Constructor<T>): QueryBuilder<T>;
}

class Person extends Model {
  name: string;
}
```

Wrapper:

```
function findById<T extends Model>(
  model: { query(): QueryBuilder<T> }
) {
  return (id: string) => model.query().findById(id);
}
```

Implementation for Person:

```
import Person from 'models/person';

const findById = Wrapper.findById(Person);
```

I would hope that the return type of the implementation would have been inferred as `Promise<Person | undefined>`, however it is instead inferred as `Promise<any>`.

Even when adding some extra typing to the wrapper function (to try and avoid any Objection-level typing issues that may exist):

```
function findById<T extends Base>(
  model: { query(): QueryBuilder<T> }
) {
  return (id: string): Promise<T | undefined> => model.query().findById(id);
}
```

The implementation still states a return type of `Promise<any>`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to achieve what I'm after here?

Comment: Could you add the type of `QueryBuilder<T>` as well?

Comment: `QueryBuilder<T>` comes from [Objection](http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#querybuilder)